# Insert subtitles permanently and convert video

Tags: video, conversion, subtitle

I need to do two things with an `.avi` video:

1. Insert subtitles (`.srt`) permanently without modifying its timing or the video intself.
2. Convert the new video (with the permanent subtitles) from `.avi` to `.mpeg`.

Is there any way to do it in one or two command lines? (Probably using `ffmpeg`?)

**Some additional data:**

- Subtitles could have some special characters (spanish characters, like: ñ, á, ü ...)
- Doesn't matter the order of events: first add subtitles to `.avi` and then convert or first convert and then add subtitles to `.mpeg`
- I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal).

Answer (score 15):

Arista can do both of these things, and it provides a very nice, easy GUI. It's available in the repos.

[image: Screen of Arista]

Comment: How can I insert the SRT file with Arista?

Comment: After choosing the file, click the configuration icon next to it and select the subtitles file to embed.

Comment: I've downloaded and installed Arista -- but how do I run it?

Answer (score 8):

Try using `mencoder`. Something like this works:

```
mencoder source.avi -sub srt.srt -o destination.mpeg -oac mp3lame -ovc lavc -of mpeg
```

mencoder has a gazillion CLI switches to control video quality, for some ideas see here (specifically about encoding to mpeg):

http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/menc-feat-mpeg.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use Mobile Media Converter to do these task.

[image: Mobile Media Converter subtitles window]

You can download from [here](https://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.php).

Comment: To be honest, of all the options tried (even VLC) this is the only thing that worked as I expected. In all other cases subtitles just would be rendered. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the Arista:

1. Select *"Create Conversion"* to get the *"Create Conversion"* window
2. Select *"Choose File..."* as the *"Source"*
3. Select the video file
4. Click on the *"gear"* next to the *"Source"* to get the *"Source
   Properties"* window
5. Set *"Subtitles to render"*

Answer (score 1):

I have success with:

```
ffmpeg -i subs.srt subs.ass
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf "ass=subs.ass" output.avi
```

But I needed to recompile ffmpeg with option `--enable-libass`.