# Subtitle editor for 16.04

Tags: 16.04, editor, subtitle

I normally get English subs for certain movies. I want to translate them to my regional language. Is there any subtitle editor for 16.04 using which I can open an .srt file and edit it to replace English text to that of my choice ?

In short, I am looking a program which can open .srt files as text and allows editing the text and saving them

PS : I am using Unity 7

Comment: I'm just gonna say this to Googlers: have a look at YouTube's subtitle management. If you upload a video, it does an automated speech to text for you, which already gets 95% of the sentences right if you speak clearly, and allows you to edit corrections manually on the website. You can then even download the subtitles locally as a text format (SBV, not widely used, but VLC can already read it: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=127504 ) This is a HUGE time saver if you are creating subtitles from scratch.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have not used them, but here are programs available on Ubuntu that can edit `.srt` files:

- Gaupol
- Gnome Subtitles
- Subtitle Editor
- Subtitle Composer (for KDE)

You can install them with the following commands:

- `sudo apt install gaupol`
- `sudo apt install gnome-subtitles`
- `sudo apt install subtitleeditor`
- `sudo apt install subtitlecomposer`

Answer (score 2):

In Linux you can edit the .srt with any common text editor. If you are looking for something more professional the best, Aegisub and Subtitle Composer. Look for them in the Software Center or use the terminal:

```
sudo apt install subtitlecomposer aegisub -y
```

Optional, simpler:

```
sudo apt install gaupol gnome-subtitles subtitleeditor -y
```

Comment: Editing subtitles with a text editor takes much too long compared to using a decent subtitle editor application like gnome-subtitles.

Answer (score 1):

I am developing a subtitle editor called "Subtitld" and you can download it from Snap Store (https://snapcraft.io/subtitld).

https://subtitld.jonata.org

Any feedback is appreciated :)